# Are questions about learning resources allowed?

Tags: discussion

Is it allowed to ask questions about the learning resources that exist (especially online) for learners of the German languages?

For example, questions about online German courses, or grammar summaries, or learn-by-radio courses. Or then again, about language exchanges for tandem learning, or anything like that.

I believe there is a great potential for the exchange of useful information about this, and possibly some interesting community wikis.

Answer (score 2):

As much as we would love to see well maintained Community Wikis on learning resources we unfortunately had to realize that in general such questions are not a good fit to the question & answer model of StackExchange sites:

- [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)
- [The halting problem - or - the fallacy of "real questions have answers"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75674/the-halting-problem-or-the-fallacy-of-real-questions-have-answers)
- [Please add "discussion" as a close reason or a subset of "Not A Real Question" or "Off-Topic"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90515/please-add-discussion-as-a-close-reason-or-a-subset-of-not-a-real-question-o)
- [Should polls be maintained as Community Wiki questions, or should they be closed?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75168/should-polls-be-maintained-as-community-wiki-questions-or-should-they-be-closed)
- [Real Questions Have Answers](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)

Whenever opinion based questions arise we inevitable will be faced with a big list of unsorted answers. This makes them almost impossible to maintain. Often good answers will appear on the bottom side of such a list only. They will not draw enough attention to get upvoted for pushing them further up. Therefore we decided to **not allow  such questions** and recommend to close them as "primarily opinion-based".

Still, we do **as an exception** have some big-list questions open for additions whenever somebody feels they have something important to contribute. These questions mostly will be "protected" to avoid spam or poor answers from new users.

For a better access to learning resource recommendations user Gigili adapted a "master" question from other sites. This question includes a TOC to make answers easier to find.

- [Resources for learning German](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/9526/resources-for-learning-german)

The question and all answers are "Community Wiki" to ease maintenance, and to let everybody contribute by edits. Whenever we feel a resource or topic is missing we may add it to the TOC at the bottom of the question, add our contribution to an existing answer, or write an own answer there.

Having such a general question on "learning resources" also means that future questions on this topic will likely be closed as a duplicate to this question.

Comment: Would my post from [here](http://german.stackexchange.com/a/8655/3183) be valid content for the "Television" section in that resource thread?

Comment: @npst: yeah - looks good to me - merged your answer - thanks for pointing to that :)

Answer (score 1):

We have had some of these in the past, and I see no harm in them.